# Nodejs response too large?

Tags: javascript, json, node.js

When I respond to an HTTP request with a large json (nodejs) the response gets cut and I get the following message (firefox):

SyntaxError:JSON.parse:unterminated string at column 1049525 of the JSON data.

Firefox apparently does not receive the entire JSON. I have concluded that the nodejs **response** does not send data larger than  1,049,525 bytes. It seems rather unlikely that this is an absolute limit because the JSON is not that large. 
I tried creating a string but got the same result.

How can I adjust the size of the file the **response** can handle? Is streaming a better way to accomplish this? Is there something else going on? Thank you...

Comment: What happens when you use `curl` or `wget` with the URL?

Comment: This is an interesting question which I have not though of before or, really haven't encounter yet. I think streaming could be the best way out. 
I did a quick search for you and found the `Oboe.js` package which could help solve your problem. Still I don't think 1mb data is that big, there could be some underlying issue. Probably also look into printing the actual JSON content and make sure they are indeed truncated.

Comment: Yes , printed the contents and there are truncated. Thank you for the Oboe.js. suggestion Samuel. I have tried streaming but consider it to more suitable for much larger files where server memory is to be conserved. I do not know how it will perform time wise on a single, smaller request for data. As far as curl, I am not familiar with it. This was a post request; it should have been able to handle the size. Thanks for your input pointy